# Remove Purge duplicate/multiplicate records from mariadb

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mariadb

Briefly: database imported from foreign source, so I cannot prevent duplicates, I can only prune and clean the database.
Foreign db changes daily, so, I want to automate the pruning process.

It resides on:
MariaDB v10.4.6 managed predominantly by phpMyadmin GUI v4.9.0.1 (both pretty much up to date as of this writing).

This is a radio browsing database.

It has multiple columns, but for me there are only few important:
StationID (it is unique entry number, thus db does not consider new entries as duplicates, all of them are unique because of this primary key)
There are no row numbers.
Name, url, home-page, country, etc
I do want to remove multiple url duplicated entries base on:
duplicate url has country to it, but some country values are NULL (=empty)
so I do want remove all duplicates except one containing country name, if there is one entry with it, if there is none, just one url, regardless of name (names are multilingual, so some duplicated urls have also various names, which I do not care for.

- `StationID` (unique number, but not consecutive, also this is primary db key)
- `Name` (variable, least important)
- `url` (variable, but I do want to remove the duplicates)
- `country` (variable, frequently `NULL`/empty, I want to eliminate those with empty entries as much as possible, if possible)
- One url has to stay by any means (not to be deleted)

I have tried multitude of queries, some work for `SELECT`, but do NOT for `DELETE`, some hang my machine when executed. Here are some queries I tried (remember I use MariaDB, not oracle, or ms-sql)

```
SELECT * from `radio`.`Station`
WHERE  (`radio`.`Station`.`Url`, `radio`.`Station`.`Name`) IN (
  SELECT `radio`.`Station`.`Url`, `radio`.`Station`.`Name`
  FROM   `radio`.`Station`
  GROUP  BY `radio`.`Station`.`Url`, `radio`.`Station`.`Name`
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

This one should show all entries (not only one grouped), but this query hangs my machine
This query gets me as close as possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM `radio`.`Station`
WHERE `radio`.`Station`.`StationID` NOT IN (
     SELECT MAX(`radio`.`Station`.`StationID`)
     FROM `radio`.`Station`
     GROUP BY `radio`.`Station`.`Url`,`radio`.`Station`.`Name`,`radio`.`Station`.`Country`)
```

However this query lists more entries:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`radio`.`Station`.`Url`) FROM `radio`.`Station` GROUP BY `radio`.`Station`.`Name`,`radio`.`Station`.`Url` HAVING (COUNT(`radio`.`Station`.`Url`) > 1);
```

But all of these queries group them and display only one row.
I also tried `UNION`, `INNER JOIN`, but failed.
`WITH cte AS`..., but phpMyadmin does NOT like this query, and mariadb cli also did not like it.

I also tried something of this kind, published at oracle blog, which did not work, and I really had no clue what was what in this function:

```
select * 
from   (
  select f.*, 
         count(*) over (
           partition by `radio`.`Station`.`Url`, `radio`.`Station`.`Name`
         ) ct
  from `radio`.`Station` f
)
where  ct > 1
```

I did not know what `f.*` was, query did not like ct.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
drop table if exists radio;
create table radio
(stationid int,name varchar(3),country varchar(3),url varchar(3));

insert into radio values
(1,'aaa','uk','a/b'),
(2,'bbb','can','a/b'),
(3,'bbb',null,'a/b'),
(4,'bbb',null,'b/b'),
(5,'bbb',null,'b/b');
```

You could give the null countries a unique value (using coalesce), fortunately stationid is unique so:

```
select t.stationid,t.name,t.country,t.url
from radio t
join
(select url,max(coalesce(country,stationid)) cntry from radio t group by url) s 
on s.url = t.url and s.cntry= coalesce(t.country,t.stationid);
```

Yields

```
+-----------+------+---------+------+
| stationid | name | country | url  |
+-----------+------+---------+------+
|         1 | aaa  | uk      | a/b  |
|         5 | bbb  | NULL    | b/b  |
+-----------+------+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Translated to a delete

```
delete t from radio t 
join
(select url,max(coalesce(country,stationid)) cntry from radio t group by url) s 
on s.url = t.url and s.cntry <> coalesce(t.country,t.stationid);

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from radio;
+-----------+------+---------+------+
| stationid | name | country | url  |
+-----------+------+---------+------+
|         1 | aaa  | uk      | a/b  |
|         5 | bbb  | NULL    | b/b  |
+-----------+------+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @ P.Salmon: Thanks for your response. However, the SELECT query provided, does not seem to work as expected, it selects almost entire database. Which, I do not think has this many duplicates. I did not try DELETE, since I was affraid to wipe out almost entire db.

Comment: It would help if you provided sample data and expected output either here as text or sqlfiddle.

Comment: 'does not seem to work as expected' -does for me, these are the keepers not the candidates for deletion. If you are going to test this please either do so on a backup copy of the db on a dev box or generate enough test data to satisfy yourself that you understand the logic.Also note the slight (but important) difference in the on clauses. If you change the on clause in the select to match the on clause in the delete then it should show candidates for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Fix 2 problems at once:

- Dup rows *already* in table
- Dup rows can still be put in table

Do this fore each table:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
ALTER TABLE new ADD UNIQUE(x,y);  -- will prevent future dups
INSERT IGNORE INTO new         -- IGNORE dups
    SELECT * FROM real;
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```